# Почему может не работать nth child?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Почему может не работать nth child в данном случае ?  Нужно что бы второй параграф оказался ниже первого на 24 пикселя.

```
https://codepen.io/camobap6/pen/MWKKEbQ
```

```css
.root {
    min-width: 240px;
    max-width:1280px;
    background-color: #2A2C2F;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: 'Inter' Arial sans-serif;
}

.places {
   
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: calc(100% - 295px);
  
}

.place {
  border:solid red 1px;
    margin: 80px auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 40px 40px;
    max-width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: 460px 1fr;
}

.place__title {
    margin:0;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 72px;
    line-height: 76px;
  max-width: 460px;
  height:150px
}
.place__image {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 460px;
  height:460px;
  
}
.place__paragraph {
    margin: 0 0 24px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 30px;
   align-self: end;
  color:white;
   margin: 0 auto;
    color: white;
    align-self: start;
  
}
.place__website-link {
 max-width: 456px;
max-height: 22px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 22px;
text-decoration-line: underline;
color: #FFFFFF; 
  margin-top:130px;
}

.place__paragraph:nth-child(2){
  margin:24px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class=root> 
<section class="places">
            <div class="place">
                <h2 class="place__title">Куршская коса</h2>
             
              <a class="place__website-link" href="http://park-kosa.ru/" title="park-kosa.ru">park-kosa.ru</a>
                <img class="place__image" src="https://www.ixbt.com/img/n1/news/2019/5/3/chrome-73-mode-sombre-android_large.jpg" alt="">
                
                <p class="place__paragraph">Здесь, посреди лесов и песчаных дюн, вы сможете увидеть два водных горизонта - спокойного Куршского залива с одной стороны и подёрнутого рябью волн Балтийского моря с другой. Уникальная природная зона на берегу российского анклава.</p>
              <p class="place__paragraph">Здесь, посреди лесов и песчаных дюн, вы сможете увидеть два водных горизонта - спокойного Куршского залива с одной стороны и подёрнутого рябью волн Балтийского моря с другой. Уникальная природная зона на берегу российского анклава.</p>
            
                
            </div>
  </section>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Это не работает потому, что параграф не является вторым ребёнком в своём родителе. В данном случае, чтобы выбрать второй тег с классом `place__paragraph` в своём родителе, можно использовать псевдокласс [nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type):

```css
.root {
    min-width: 240px;
    max-width:1280px;
    background-color: #2A2C2F;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: 'Inter' Arial sans-serif;
}

.places {
   
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: calc(100% - 295px);
  
}

.place {
  border:solid red 1px;
    margin: 80px auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 40px 40px;
    max-width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: 460px 1fr;
}

.place__title {
    margin:0;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 72px;
    line-height: 76px;
  max-width: 460px;
  height:150px
}
.place__image {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 460px;
  height:460px;
  
}
.place__paragraph {
    margin: 0 0 24px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 30px;
   align-self: end;
  color:white;
   margin: 0 auto;
    color: white;
    align-self: start;
  
}
.place__website-link {
 max-width: 456px;
max-height: 22px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 22px;
text-decoration-line: underline;
color: #FFFFFF; 
  margin-top:130px;
}

.place__paragraph:nth-of-type(2){
  margin:100px 0px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class=root> 
  <section class="places">
            <div class="place">
                <h2 class="place__title">Куршская коса</h2>
             
              <a class="place__website-link" href="http://park-kosa.ru/" title="park-kosa.ru">park-kosa.ru</a>
                <img class="place__image" src="https://www.ixbt.com/img/n1/news/2019/5/3/chrome-73-mode-sombre-android_large.jpg" alt="">
              <div>
                <p class="place__paragraph">Здесь, посреди лесов и песчаных дюн, вы сможете увидеть два водных горизонта - спокойного Куршского залива с одной стороны и подёрнутого рябью волн Балтийского моря с другой. Уникальная природная зона на берегу российского анклава.</p>
              <p class="place__paragraph">Здесь, посреди лесов и песчаных дюн, вы сможете увидеть два водных горизонта - спокойного Куршского залива с одной стороны и подёрнутого рябью волн Балтийского моря с другой. Уникальная природная зона на берегу российского анклава.</p>
            </div>
                
            </div>
  </section>
<div>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109182/discussion-on-answer-by-egbro-----nth-child).